# Snakeskin geometry tightening

Tags: texturing, displacement

I'm trying to create a displacement map for realistic snakeskin. Have tried 'cutting' into the skin to create the creases between scales...but looking at reference photos the scales are really tight. Each scale bulges, almost overlapping the next. Would I be better to use spheres and deform them/bulge them somehow?  How might I achieve this bulging?

[image]

(edit) some way there to figuring this out. modelled a singular scale and using a particle system with very slight random variations across particle system.

[image]

(edit 2) exported rough displacement map (need to make seamless somehow while retaining randomness from particles...) added some noise and basic material

[image]

Comment: Later on I'll provide this method: https://imgur.com/U7AQPQO it's pure mesh based approach with modifiers workflow, so it's pretty non-destructible.

Comment: [The osl script here](https://github.com/sambler/osl-shaders/tree/master/patterns/MAscales) makes a good scales texture.